# How to help a wild baby parrot who cannot fly?

Tags: parrots, animal-handling

3 days ago a baby parrot was found in my garden, we are not sure from where this bird came from.  We soon discovered that he cannot fly, at this time we are trying to keep him safe from predators.

His flight feathers look to be cut with scissors, we entice him to fly but he doesn't.

I don't have much experience with pets. I'm looking for advice as to what we can do to help him thrive in the wild.

Should we visit a veterinarian for the clipped feathers?

I read they get back feathers, how much time does it take?

Edit: There was one more thing, may be leas important here. Next day one more baby parrot came to my home, we kept both of them together in open. This one stayed one day and night and flew away next morning.

Adding Image as requested in comments.

[image]

Here is picture of the other bird I was referring, you can compare and see this one has wings.
[image]

Edit2:
Today parrot flew away, I am happy for him.

This is no more a question for me but answer will still help others.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.Se Vipin, are you able to post photos of the bird? As well as show us his/her wings.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Added picture

Comment: It looks like the first one is someones pet, some people clip their wings to attempt to prevent flight (doesn't really work).

Comment: Are these species known to live in the wild where you are?

Comment: Note about scope, while the question implies this a wild bird (which would be out of scope) the clipped wings imply an escaped pet bird (in scope)

Comment: @RebeccaRVT this one was funny :) , I am in small town not wild area. This is common species in India.

Answer (score 2):

Look for or post lost/found bird notice in your area.

Trimmed flight feathers imply the bird is a pet who escaped.

> flight feathers look to be cut with scissors

Also look for a leg band, Many pet birds (depending on country) will have a ring on their leg indicating breeding program info.  This may help you identify the birds owner.

I am not a bird expert this could be a parakeet or baby parrot.  If neither have wild cousins in your part of the world, it would definitely be an escaped pet.

If there are wild cousins in your area, and no leg band.  You might want to contact a local authority. There could be legal issues associated with caring for him.

Comment: Thats sad news someone cut feathers intentionally, i think that should have legal consequences. This bird doesnt have any band, if it was pet then there is only one possibility i see someone caught him and tried to make him pet.

Comment: This is common species of parrot in India, it doesn’t come in wild category. Unfortunately i dont find my answer here, how do we make sure parrot gets back to normal life and fly with his family again.

Comment: @Vipin Our scope is limited to pets,  We don't have experts on how to release the bird back into wild, or what measures to take while rehabilitating him for release.  Our sister site [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) might be able to provide the answer you are looking for.  Thank you for posting your question here as it does allow us to provide the answer that is scope, even though we are not able to provide the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Posted question on [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73511/how-to-help-a-wild-baby-parrot-who-cannot-fly) site as well.